# Multiple video input to Video grid using vstack and hstack in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, mosaic

I am trying to find a working example for ffmpeg to combine 4 videos (2x2 stack) and 9 videos (3x3 stack) that are not the same resolution.

For the 2x2 example I am currently I am using the documentation example but it only works if all videos are the same resolution. see command

`ffmpeg -i top_l.mp4 -i top_r.mp4 -i bottom_l.mp4 -i bottom_r.mp4 -i audio.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack[t];[2:v][3:v]hstack[b];[t][b]vstack[v]" \
-map "[v]" -an -sn -shortest -f flv rtmp://server/stream`

This does not work with my videos inputs with the following error.

`[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 0000000003245cc0] Input 1 width 1440 does not match input 0 width 1264.
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 0000000003245cc0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while decoding stream #3:0: Invalid argument
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033fec20] Input 1 width 1440 does not match input 0 width 1264.
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033fec20] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033feb40] Input 1 width 1440 does not match input 0 width 1264.
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033feb40] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033fec20] Input 1 width 1440 does not match input 0 width 1264.
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033fec20] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while decoding stream #1:0: Invalid argument
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033fece0] Input 1 width 1440 does not match input 0 width 1264.
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033fece0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while decoding stream #2:0: Invalid argument
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033ff1c0] Input 1 width 1440 does not match input 0 width 1264.
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033ff1c0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while decoding stream #3:0: Invalid argument
Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033fec20] Input 1 width 1440 does not match input 0 width 1264.
[Parsed_vstack_2 @ 00000000033fec20] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_2
Error configuring filter graph
Conversion failed!`

Also if anyone knows how to do the 3x3 stack, feel free to comment.

Comment: In a stack filter, the dimensions of the inputs at the interfaces have to be the same., So, use scale filters beforehand.

Comment: @Mulvya thats what I cant seem to do right. Can you suggest the best way to do it?